# Can I update a customized fieldgroup GUI across multiple channels?

Tags: fields

I apply a particular fieldgroup, "Common", to about 15 channels. I've customized my tabs and locations of the fields to make it easier to use. Every time I add a field, it's added to the bottom of the Publish tab, then I move it somewhere else. I don't mind doing this, but I do it times 15 channels, so it gets tedious. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. The only reason I am writing more words here is that SE didn't just let me say "no". ;)